# Automating App Deployment with Postgresql: Overcoming Challenges of Metrics Sidecar and Database Restoration

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, metrics

I have a deployment of an app with a Postgresql database. This database has a metrics sidecar.
Now, I need to restore a dump into the Postgresql before the app's pod can start.
For this purpose, I added an init container to the app that takes care of this task.
However, I'm facing a problem where the metrics sidecar establishes a connection to the database, preventing the dump from being restored. I can't use a readiness probe in the init container to check when the restoration is finished.

The reason for this effort is that this deployment should be rolled out with a single click in a Jenkins pipeline. Everything should be automated.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this problem.